# WinXP Movie Maker Codec Error

Tags: windows-xp, codec, windows-movie-maker

I'm trying to use Windows XP Movie Maker, but when I try to import an AVI video, it shows an error telling me that it wasn't import due to an the fact that the codec wasn't available (I'm able to see the video using the windows media player)

First, the error message suggested to enable the option "download codecs automatically" under "tools > options general". I did it. But know the error tells me that the codec wasn't available and, if I already installed it, I should reinitialize movie maker. I also already did it...

The error msg is:

> The file D:\movie1.avi cannot be
>   imported because the codec required to
>   play the file is not installed on your
>   computer. If you have already tried to
>   download and install the codec, close
>   and restart Windows Movie Maker, and
>   then try to import the file again.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this means you don't have the codec. Maybe [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) would do it for you? I use the Mega version and never run out of codecs (well, almost never). Note that it's free.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but no, I have the codec. As I said, I'm able to see the video using windows media player and others (such as media player classic). The problem only occurs with Movie Maker.

Comment: Maybe WMM has it's own codec library somewhere? Can you import WMV files? And, could you post the MediaInfo report on the file? (*maybe* you have it on "send to> MediaInfo" on the context menu)

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the avi in [GraphEdit](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/GraphEdit) and see which filters it is trying to use.

It may actually be the audio stream that is causing the issue.

GraphEdit will show you exactly which audio and video codecs/filters/splitters are being used.

Have you installed Haali Media Splitter and set it to split AVIs for you? Movie Maker might not like that.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. Go to the Windows Movie Maker menu item "Tools", click the Compatibility tab and see if this codec is missing a check-mark. WMM might have decided not to use it.
2. Use [Gspot](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/GSpot.htm) to see if the file really contains the codec you think it does.
3. Find another similar codec - WMM might not like the one you have.
   [K-Lite Mega Codec](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_Mega_codec_pack.htm) with FFDSHOW is very good.